# Extract a term of `Series` output

Tags: series-expansion

Say I have the output of series, with all the coefficients of the different powers of my variable $x$. What is the quickest way of extracting the coefficient of the $n$-th power of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeriesCoefficient[mySeries, n]
```

For instance:

```
mySeries = Series[Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

$
1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^5}{15}-\frac{x^6}{240}+\frac{x^7}{90}+\frac{31
   x^8}{5760}+\frac{x^9}{5670}-\frac{2951 x^{10}}{3628800}+O\left(x^{11}\right)
$

```
SeriesCoefficient[mySeries, 8]
```

$\frac{31}{5760}$